# What is a lattice parser?

Tags: algorithms, parsing, recognition

My friend asked me for help with his task: "Redeem a lattice parser with any programming language" - the problem is that he can't clearly explain me how the lattice parser should work. I've tried to google a bit, but all I've found are some academic documents which doesn't help.

All I know at the moment that it is related/used very often with speech recognition - but in our case it will be only text-based for sure.

I'm looking forward for a fine explanation how this parser works (I don't ask for a solution in any programming language - I want to do it with my friend by ourselves).

I know that this lattice parser is somehow related to Earley parser ([link to wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) and something called an academic parser - still doesn't know how it should help me to understand this.)

Comment: Initial Googling suggests that this term refers to a parser whose inputs are "[word lattices](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.WordLattices)". If no one knowledgeable comes along I might read more of these links and try to compose an actual answer.

Comment: Perhaps your friend should post the question himself.  If he can't explain it to you, then what chance do you have when it comes to explaining it to us?

Comment: I'll meet with him tomorrow and we'll start working on this topic (that's the reason why I've asked this question - I wanted to prepare anything) - I'll try to update this question when I'll get more info. I just thought that maybe it is some common knowledge question and I was the one who doesn't know what it is about but now I'm pretty sure that it will be a little harder problem.

Comment: The [polish version](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorytm_Earleya) of the wikipedia article that you linked was apparently a well written one at one time or another as it was a featured article for the site.

Answer (score -3):

Parser means converter. When we parse a String in java, means that we convert that String to other String. Everything is done using code and algorithm (code steps).

Word lattice is a graph.See detail at 
http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.WordLattices

Lattice parser perhaps means Word lattice converter. When we parse the lattice, perhaps we want to extract the lattice data (graph) and convert it to something.

Comment: This answer doesn't really provide any useful information beyond the discussions in the comments above.  Can you expand on this, perhaps?  Maybe elaborate on what kind of parsing techniques would be performed on these word lattices?  Or what kind of structure one might parse them into?